# Select value and insert to the next row by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgresql and here's my table 'test' for example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9JiW.png)
And my question is: how could I select value from 'this_time' then insert into 'next_time' group by chart_id like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUIgR.png)

now I'm trying this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTiBN.png)
could I select 'this_time' value and insert into 'next_time' by offset or row_number PARTITION?
still not get a clear idea yet...

Comment: Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056). Also, please do not post images of code or data

Comment: thanks, sorry that I didn't know can show data outcome in that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing `lead()`:

```
select chart_id, date, this_time, 
    lead(this_time) over(partition by chart_id order by this_time) as next_time
from mytable t
```

Comment: thank you sooooo much!
I've been stuck on this question for a while!